# proc_open disabled but still getting error

Tags: laravel, error-handling, proc-open

Class App\Http\Controllers\KeyfeaturesController located in ./app/Http/Controllers/KeyFeaturesController.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.

> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> Deprecation Notice: Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /home/maacareco/public_html/@core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:1405
> Deprecation Notice: Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetGet($key) should either be compatible withArrayAccess::offsetGet(mixed $offset): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /home/maacareco/public_html/@core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:1416
> Deprecation Notice: Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetSet($key, $value) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetSet(mixed $offset, mixed $value): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute shouldbe used to temporarily suppress the notice in /home/maacareco/public_html/@core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:1428
> Deprecation Notice: Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetUnset($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetUnset(mixed $offset): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /home/maacareco/public_html/@core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:1441
> Deprecation Notice: Return type of PhpOption\Some::getIterator() should either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /home/maacareco/public_html/@core/vendor/phpoption/phpoption/src/PhpOption/Some.php:152
> Deprecation Notice: Return type of PhpOption\None::getIterator() should either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /home/maacareco/public_html/@core/vendor/phpoption/phpoption/src/PhpOption/None.php:118
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi
> Deprecation Notice: Return type of Symfony\Component\Process\Process::getIterator(int $flags = 0) should either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /home/maacareco/public_html/@core/vendor/symfony/process/Process.php:620

In Process.php line 144:

The Process class relies on proc_open, which is not available on your PHP i
nstallation.

dump-autoload [-o|--optimize] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu] [--apcu-prefix APCU-PREFIX] [--dev] [--no-dev][--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--strict-psr]

I have disabled proc_open on server end still getting this error I have no idea what I need to do to solve this issue.

I've tried everything can some one get back to me with suggestion please.